# Quantum state expanded in basis or just orthonormal set

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

Consider a quantum state $\vert{\psi}⟩$. It can be expanded in the form
$$\vert{\psi}⟩=\sum_ic_i\vert{\phi_i}⟩,$$ where the vectors $\vert{\phi_i}⟩$ form an orthonormal basis. My question is, if my Hilbert space is not necessarily separable, do the $\vert{\phi_i}⟩$'s need to be a basis (in the sense of being complete) for the expansion to hold or is it enough if they are an orthonormal system?

Comment: Enough for what?

Comment: @jacob1729 I've edited my question to be more precise on what I'm asking

Comment: surely it must be complete (or overcomplete).  They don’t need to be orthogonal.

Comment: Isn't this just what the word complete means? If it isn't complete then take $\psi \in \mathcal{H} \setminus \text{Span}(|\phi_i\rangle)$ (non-empty by assumption) then that gives you a vector that cannot be decomposed.

Comment: Separability and existence of orthonormal bases are unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ were a basis, we would have $\mathrm{span}(B) = \mathcal{H}$ which means that any element of the Hilbert space is a *finite* linear combination of vectors from $B$.

Usually in quantum mechanics, $\mathrm{span}(B)$ is only dense in $\mathcal{H}$. This means that in order to get an arbitrary element, we generally need an infintie linear combination.

In this sense, what most textbooks call an "orthonormal basis" is not strictly a basis. I've personally never seen a situation in quantum mechanics where it's desirable to have a true basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Such a basis would have to be very large. And in particular, it would not be possible to write its elements as $\left | \phi_i \right>$.

As an aside, for some Banach spaces like $L^1$ and $L^\infty$, finding a basis is hard enough that it matters whether you accept the axiom of choice.

Comment: Most quantum mechanics book I've read just require the $\vert\phi >$'s to be an orthonormal system, as far as I've understood it. I just wondered how consistent it is to assume that the expansion holds.